# Angular remove class on location change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, removeclass

I want to remove a class when ever the user changes page, mostly because I want to collapse the bootstrap navbar. To do this I have created a directive that will remove a specified class. Whats the best way to trigger my directive on the $routeChangeSuccess event without listening to to the event within the directive as I would like to keep it flexible.

```
app.directive('removeClass', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             //someway to trigger this method e.g. from an event listener outside the directive 
             scope.removeClass = function() {
                  element.removeClass(attrs.removeClass);
             }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change a `$rootScope` variable with `ng-class`. Set that variable when there in a controller depending on page.

Comment: The issue with that is, I would need to find a way to unset the variable after the page had changed and the directive had run so that the navbar could then be collapsed again.

Comment: you would have to change in main controller and directive. you can change in both. Not sure why there is a issue.

Comment: In my mind it would be cleaner to have a way to trigger the directives removeClass function from the controller each time the event $routeChangeStart is triggered, rather than trying to manage and watch the state of a variable across both scopes, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Ben_hawk need more thought on that. not sure of better way right now.